# Split without Index out of bound exception

Tags: scala

Is there any simple way to split safely by avoiding index bound of exception?

For example:

```
"1-2".split("-")(1) == "2"
"1".split("-")(1) == null
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This functionality is already implemented in `Array`. `lift` method returns `None` for an out of bounds index, otherwise it returns `Some(value)`

```
val array = Array(3, 5, 1)
array.lift(5) // None
array.lift(0) // Some(3)
```

Comment: great! never seen this method

Answer (score 3):

Scala [Array](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Array.html) doesn't provide safety method to get element by index. So you should consider `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Possible ways:

use `Try` and test it if success:

`scala.util.Try(array(index))`

add own method:

```
implicit class RichArray[A](array: Array[A]) {
  def opt(index: Int): Option[A] =
    if (array.length < 0 || array.length <= index) None
    else Some(array(index))
}

val array = Array(12, 3, 4)

array.opt(2) // Some(4)
array.opt(3) // None
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your Operation using `scala.util.Try` and then do `getOrElse` over it. If the value at that index exists it will return that value else it will return the value specified in `getOrElse`. Try following code for your above given scenario.

```
scala.util.Try("1".split("-")(1)).getOrElse(null)
//output
null
```